# Passing variables with Python MySQL connector

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

So I have a Python script that is for all intents and purposes going to sync Discord with my website. I am saving the messages to a database or trying to anyway. I keep getting an error saying there is an error with my syntax. I have been through all the documentation on the matter multiple times and still haven't found a reason or solution. Below is the part of the script I am working with right now. Any ideas are appreciated! The print yes and print no are just for diagnostics until I have it working. Ultimately, there will be a lot more script in each space.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    guild = message.guild
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
    author=message.author
    headers=(guild,author)
    if guild in mycursor:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
        mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s",guild)
        mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (message VARCHAR(255) %s (author VARCHAR(255)",headers)
```

Here is the error I get.

```
root@viktor:~# python3 bot2.py
Bot Loaded
no  # <---- (This is the print no if there is not a database with the same name as the guild.)
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot2.py", line 95, in on_message
    mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s",guild)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so still not sure what the issue is but I did find a resolution.

I simply changed the way I setup the command to execute.

```
cmd="CREATE DATABASE " + guild
mycursor.execute(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
> mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (message VARCHAR(255)",channel)
> ```

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the query/command here.

In the future, you should provide the full traceback when asking about a specific error.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question to include the error now. I was very tired when I posted that and wasn't thinking. My understanding is that it expects a tuple of variables but since I only have one I have tried the variable, tried converting the variable to a tuple, and nothing seems to work. I just get iteration messages and honestly I don't understand iteration at all.

Comment: Ah, after seeing the traceback, the issue, before even encountering the missing closing parenthesis, is that you can't pass database and table names as parameters in prepared statements. You'll want to manually concatenate the query, using [`escape_string`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html) to avoid injection.